# Apply Rotation & Scale problem

Tags: modeling

When applying Rotation & Scale to an object the mesh seems to invert. What is happening here and how can I prevent / correct it?

[image]

Comment: Does the scale showing minus values before you apply the scale?

Comment: Seems that you have negative scale and Backface Culling turned on; thus when normals get inverted you see the inside of the object. Use Ctrl+N to fix them

Comment: @Denis You were absolutely correct, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the scale, try going into edit mode, selecting all faces and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

If that doesn't help, it would be nice if you could upload a .blend file.